# Tratando um input do tipo string quando aperto enter sem digitar nada

Tags: python, python-3.x

Fala galera!
Se alguém puder me ajudar?

Quando ele me pergunta se eu quero continuar e eu aperto enter sem digitar nada ele me deixa prosseguir. Eu gostaria que quando eu apertar o enter sem digitar nada ele não me deixe continuar, somente se eu digitar o 'Ss' ou o 'Nn'. 
Como eu trato essa string em branco?
Valeu...

```
soma = media = cont =  0
maior = menor = 0
r = 'Ss'

while r != 'Nn':
    while True:
        try:
            n = float(input('Digite um número inteiro: '))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('Entrada Inválida!')
    soma += n
    cont += 1
    if cont == 1:
        maior = n
        menor = n
    if n > maior:
        maior = n
    elif n < menor:
        menor = n
    r = str(input('Quer continuar? S/N? ')).strip()
    while r not in 'Ss' and r not in 'Nn':
        r = str(input('Quer continuar? S/N?' ')).strip()
    if r not in 'Ss':
        r = 'Nn'
media = soma / cont

print('\033[36m<=>\033[m'*10)
print('Foram digitados \033[32m{}\033[m números e a \033[32mmédia\033[m entre eles foi de \033[32m{:.2f}\033[m.'.format(cont, media))        
print('O \033[32mmaior\033[m número digitado foi \033[32m{}\033[m.'.format(maior))
print('O \033[32mmenor\033[m número digitado foi \033[32m{}\033[m.'.format(menor))
```

Comment: `while r not in 'Ss' and r not in 'Nn':` perceba que é uma and, não uma or

Comment: Valeu. A questão é que quando eu não dígito nada ele prossegui com o código. Eu gostaria de tratar isso. Já usei o or mais ele fica dentro do loop eternamente. A questão aqui é tratar a string  em branco, senão me engano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução que eu encontrei foi dividir o script em duas funções `continuar` e `fazer`.

Sugiro que primeiro teste desta forma sem fazer alteração alguma e em seguida incremente o método `fazer`.

```
resposta = True


def continuar():    

    resposta = input('\nQuer continuar? [S/N] ')    
    resposta = resposta[0:1].lower() # Simplificando a resposta em apenas um caractere minúsculo

    if resposta == "s":
        return True

    elif resposta == "n":        
        return False

    else:
        continuar()


def fazer():

    n = 0

    try:
        n = int(input('\nDigite um número inteiro: '))        
        return n

    except ValueError:        
        print('Entrada Inválida!')        
        return False


while resposta != False:

    n = fazer()

    if n: # Se n não for False
        print("Saída:", n)        
        resposta = continuar()

    elif resposta: # Se resposta não for False        
        fazer()
```

Comment: Testei sem alteração e funcionou. Agora é só imcrementar a função fazer. Valeu pela força.

Comment: Fico feliz em ajudar, peço por gentileza que marque a minha resposta como certa . Abraço e até a próxima!

Comment: Com certeza. É minha primeira postagem aqui. Ainda estou aprendendo. Eu só ainda não consegui incrementar a função, mas chego lá. Até a próxima!

Comment: Obrigado Myckel, se precisar de mais ajuda elabore uma nova pergunta. Abraço e bom estudo!

Comment: Valeu Éder. Só pra ajudar a galera,  eu consegui resolver esse meu código de uma outra forma. Vou postar o código...

Answer (score 0):

```
soma = media = cont =  0
maior = menor = 0
r = 's'

while r != 'n':

    while True:

        try:
            n = float(input('Digite um número inteiro: '))
            break

        except ValueError:
            print('Entrada Inválida!')

    soma += n
    cont += 1

    if cont == 1:
        maior = n
        menor = n

    if n > maior:
        maior = n

    elif n < menor:
        menor = n

    r = str(input('Quer continuar? S/N? ')).strip()

    while (r not in 's' and r not in 'n') or r == '':
        r = str(input('Quer continuar? S/N? ')).strip()

    if r not in 's':
        r = 'n'

media = soma / cont

print('\033[36m<=>\033[m'*10)
print('Foram digitados \033[32m{}\033[m números e a \033[32mmédia\033[m entre eles foi de \033[32m{:.2f}\033[m.'.format(cont, media))        
print('O \033[32mmaior\033[m número digitado foi \033[32m{}\033[m.'.format(maior))
print('O \033[32mmenor\033[m número digitado foi \033[32m{}\033[m.'.format(menor))
```

Comment: Eu tenho programado no celular, estou sem computador, parecia que o código estava bem editado, não sei o que aconteceu. Programar no celular é complicado.Foi mal aê.. Valeu pela edição...